# UITableView Show a "loading spinner" when scrolled passed bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to show a "spinner" at the bottom of my table (like the current Twitter iPhone App) when my users scroll passed the last cell in my table.

I thought about adding a static cell and adding 1 additional row to show the cell at the bottom, however, I think this is going to look crappy if I only have, say, 2 cells.

I looked through a bunch of Google searches, however, I didn't really see an answer. I thought about pulling up a "loading view" once my scroll view for the table reached a certain point, however, I think I may be over-thinking the situation.

Any help or direction would be awesome... thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [UIRefreshControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html) to trigger your UIActivityController.

Comment: I have one at the top for refreshing the table, I want one at the bottom for loading more "pages"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you add a `UIActivityIndicator` to a view and set that view as the UITableView's footer view.

Comment: I tried that... but it keeps it there all the time?

Comment: After you load the data, set the table's footer back to nil